# Which package of MySQL should I choose from the software center?

Tags: mysql

When installation MySQL in ubuntu software center There are two programs

1. Mysql server
2. Mysql client

Whichever is chosen for the installation MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install both client and server

**Server:**  Which manages your database and stores data.

**Client:**  Provides an interface to run the SQL